# Create a slide transition on click from one div to another

Tags: css, css-transitions

[image]

How to make this transition with CSS.

I am doing something similar https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BYYQOr here.

```
#container {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
#div1, #div2 {
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}

#div2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
}


.show {
  -o-transition: opacity 3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 3s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 3s;
  transition: opacity 3s;
  opacity:1;
}
.hide{  opacity:0; right: -200px; }
```

How do I do ease in ease out using the above please help

Comment: You can use transition-timing-function: ease-in; Codepen: https://codepen.io/YasirKamdar/pen/dddNvZ

Comment: @Yasir Thanks so much how do we translate from right to left though

Comment: https://codepen.io/YasirKamdar/pen/vddgmR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use transition-timing-function

```
#container {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
#div1, #div2 {
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}

#div2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
}


 .show {
         -o-transition: opacity 3s;
         -moz-transition: opacity 3s;
         -webkit-transition: opacity 3s;
         transition: opacity 3s;
          opacity:1;
   /* This timing applies on the way OUT */
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  /* Hide thing by pushing it outside by default */
  transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    .hide{  
      opacity:0; 
      /* This timing applies on the way IN */
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;

  /* A litttttle slower on the way in */
  transition: 1.25s;

  /* Move into place */
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```